# Timebar/Seek Buttons are disabled in Exoplayer for some .mkv files and hevc files

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

It works for some mkv files perfectly but for some mkv files it does not show scrubber on time bar and when i try to seek video programmatically it starts from beginning

[image: enter code here]

```
simplexo = ExoPlayer.Builder(this,DefaultRenderersFactory(this)).build()
val datasource = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,Util.getUserAgent(this,"app"))
concatenate = ConcatenatingMediaSource()
val mediasource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(datasource).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(ok.get(position.toInt()).path))
concatenate.addMediaSource(mediasource)
    
playerview.setPlayer(simplexo)
simplexo.prepare(concatenate)

simplexo.seekTo(position.toInt(),C.TIME_UNSET)
simplexo.setPlayWhenReady(true)
```